# Getting "invalid expression term" ERROR when using the += operator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I use Visual Studio. This is the code that I struggle with:

```
double answer = 0;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   {
        try
        {
            double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(this.textBox1.Text);
            double answer += value1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error on input dummy", "Warning");
        }
     }
}
```

I have created a button which runs the above code. 
I *think* that I have set up the variable properly, but I'm not entirely sure. I need another button to have access to it and I'm not entirely sure what to do about this.

All I need to know is why the `+=` on line **9** gives me an ERROR and what changes I need to make to solve this, since I'm not sure.

Comment: `+=` adds to the value of an *existing* variable. You're declaring a *new* variable `answer` here... It doesn't have a previous value. What value do you want it to have? If you're just trying to assign to the field, remove the `double` on the line that's failing

Comment: Change `double answer += value1;` to `answer += value1;`.

Comment: https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/1330430245384679424?s=20

Comment: If any answer helps you, please [vote on it or mark it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

When you say `double answer += value1;` you're declaring a variable called `answer`. Since you're already declared it earlier, you'll get an error.

You should just add the value without declaring the variable like this:

```
answer += value1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line with new line.

```
double answer += value1;
```

to

```
answer += value1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the `answer` defined, Just change this line

```
double answer += value1;
```

to

```
answer += value1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer variable defined.
Correction below
note: I suggest using double.TryParse.

```
double answer;

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                double value1;
                if (double.TryParse(this.textBox1.Text, out value1))
                {
                    answer += value1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error on input dummy", "Warning");
            }
        }
```